# pulling data from date field in google app engine form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, date

I have created a simple form in GAE-python which contains a date field.
i tried pulling in the data from it but keep on getting an exception.
my code is;

```
temp_var = datetime.strptime(cgi.escape(self.request.get('exam_date')),"%m/%d/%Y")
pledge_data.checkup_date = temp_var.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

the exception is;

```
BadValueError: Property checkup_date must be a date
```

i am confused here. shouldn't strftime convert it to a date object?

EDIT: the date i am parsing is a string "05/23/2011"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are doing a strptime on the exam_date which returns you a date 
and right after you are reconverting it to a string with strftime

try:

```
temp_var = datetime.strptime(cgi.escape(self.request.get('exam_date')),"%m/%d/%Y")
pledge_data.checkup_date = temp_var
```

Answer (score 1):

With the first line you already get a date:

```
temp_var = datetime.strptime("05/23/2011","%m/%d/%Y")

temp_var
>> datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 23, 0, 0)
```

Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).